# Laravel $schedule to read/send email

Tags: php, laravel

I´m trying to create `$schedule` job in `Laravel` to read `Email` with [PHP IMAP](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) package. If I go to route, package read email and does all correctly, but need to do this every `5` minutes.

I create a `new` command class and add this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReadMail extends Command implements SelfHandling {

protected $name = 'read:mail';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function fire()
{
    $request = Request::create($this->option('App\Http\Controllers\MailController@index'), 'GET');
    $this->info(app()['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']->handle($request));
}
```

In `kernel`

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\ReadMail',
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->call('read:mail')
     ->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

I'm not sure if this code it´is correct, but does not work properly. Any idea about it?

Thank in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

I launch this

`php artisan read:mail` and return

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Console\Application::add() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command, instance of App\Commands\ReadMail given`

The code of ReadMail class

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReadMail extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $signature = 'read:mail';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $request = Request::create($this->option('App\Http\Controllers\MailController@index'), 'GET');
        $this->info(app()['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']->handle($request));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED - ALL CODE**

Kernel

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Commands\ReadMail',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->command('read:mail')
        ->everyFiveMinutes();
    }

}
```

ReadMail

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;

class ReadMail extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $name = 'read:mail';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       MailController::index();
    }
}
```

MailController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PhpImap\Mailbox as ImapMailbox;

use App\Models\Escalas;

class MailController extends Controller {

    public static function index()
    {

    $mailbox = new ImapMailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', '', '','');

    $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('UNSEEN');
    if(!$mailsIds) {
        die('Mailbox is empty');
    }

    $mail=[];

    foreach ($mailsIds as $index=>$data){
        $mail[]=$mailbox->getMail($mailsIds[$index]);
        Escalas::insert([
            ['' => $mail[$index]->textPlain, 
            '' => $mail[$index]->date,
            ''=>$mail[$index]->subject,
            ''=>$mail[$index]->fromName,
            ''=>$mail[$index]->fromAddress,
            ''=>$mail[$index]->toString],
        ]);
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check if your artisan command is executable.

Comment: what happens if you fire php artisan read:mail  ?

Comment: Class App\Console\Commands\ReadMail does not exist. Ops, don´t see this error.

Comment: Could you add a tag which Laravel version you are using? Might be useful for later visitors to this question.

Comment: Laravel 5.0. But problem does not resolve. Question updated.

Comment: Add `parent::__construct();` to the constructor. This will run the constructor of the parent class as well (the Symfony command class in this case)

Could you also show us the `App\Commands\Command`class this one is extending from?

Comment: Cannot call constructor with parent::__construct();. Whatever,  App\Commands\Command has a abstract class Command, but empty.

Comment: Your command should extend the Illuminate Command class and also trigger this class' constructor. Extending your own command class (by `use App\Commands\Command;`) might have caused the issue. I'd recommend extending the Illuminate Command and giving it a go. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159890/discussion-between-bert-h-and-el-hombre-sin-nombre).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing
`protected $name = 'read:mail';`
 with `protected $signature= 'read:mail';`

in your `ReadMail` class and then run in `Kernel` like this

`$schedule->command('read:mail')->everyFiveMinutes();`

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check whether your scheduled tasks are set up properly** (see [docs for Laravel 5.0](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands)) Make sure you've added a cronjob to trigger Laravel's scheduled commands. To check you cronjobs are running, look for a file like /logs/crond.log. When opening this file, you should see lines showing at what times this ran. This is the command that triggers Laravel's scheduled jobs.
2. If all that is correct, then **try running your command via your terminal on localhost** to check the command is all set. This should reveal any problems with the command setup. Your functionality itself seems allright, since you mentioned everything works when triggered via a route.